# Undefined index: Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I had 2 tables . driver and part_time_available, when I select driver type parttime it'll show part_time_available field. the problem is I can't save.

it throws this error : Undefined index: start_time

here's my save controller code so far :

```
public function saveHandler(Request $request, $obj)
{
    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();
            $obj->fill($request->all());
            if (!$obj->save()) {
                throw new ValidationException($obj->errors());
            }
            foreach($request->parttimeAvailabilities as $pta) {
                \Log::info($pta);
                if (empty($pta['id'])) { 
                    $parttimeAvailability = new PartTimeAvailability();
                }
                else {
                    $parttimeAvailability = PartTimeAvailability::find($pta['id']);
                }
                $parttimeAvailability->driver()->associate($obj);
                $pta['driver_id'] = isset($pta['driver_id']);
                $parttimeAvailability->day = $pta['day'];
                $parttimeAvailability->start_time = $pta['start_time'];
                $parttimeAvailability->end_time = $pta['end_time'];
                $parttimeAvailability->available = isset($pta['available']);
                $parttimeAvailability->save();
            };
            $obj->save();
            if (!$parttimeAvailability->save()) {
                throw new ValidationException($parttimeAvailability->errors());
            }
        DB::commit();
        return $this->sendSuccessResponse($request);
    } catch (ValidationException $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        \Log::error($e->errors);
        return $this->sendErrorResponse($request, $e->errors);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        \Log::error($e->getMessage());
        return $this->sendErrorResponse($request,'Unable to process. Please contact system Administrator');
    }

}
```

here's my view form code :

```
<?php $index = 0; ?>
@foreach($dayOfWeek as $key => $day )
<div class="parttime">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::text('parttimeAvailabilities['.$index.'][day]',$day, ['class' => 'form-control','disabled'])!!}
                {!! Form::hidden('parttimeAvailabilities['.$index.'][day]',$key, ['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
                {!! Form::hidden('parttimeAvailabilities['.$index.'][id]',null) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::text('parttimeAvailabilities['.$index.'][start_time]', null, ['class' => 'form-control start_time','placeholder' => 'Start time'])!!}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::text('parttimeAvailabilities['.$index.'][end_time]', null, ['class' => 'form-control end_time','placeholder' => 'End time'])!!}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::text('parttimeAvailabilities['.$index.'][hours]', null, ['id' => 'hours','class' => 'form-control', 'readonly'])!!}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 text-center">
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::checkbox('parttimeAvailabilities['.$index.'][available]')!!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php $index++; ?>
@endforeach
```

any idea ?

Comment: We need your view as well. Just sounds like a generic array error. `start_time` in your `$pta` variable doesn't exist. It's not being sent properly with the request.

Comment: @SteveBauman updated view form.

Comment: Are you using dev tools (specifically the network tab) and inspect the post or get request to make sure index is being posted with the request? This sounds like laravel is not getting the index during the request.

Comment: @Birdy sorry, i don't get it , what do you mean by dev tools ?

Comment: Web developer tools on your browser, for example Firefox would be tools > Web developer > Network (Ctrl+Shift+Q).  Another option would be to add:   return $request->all(); at the top of your saveHandler function so it puts the full request to your screen and see exactly whats being passed in the request.

Comment: @Birdy yeah Im using it. the issue is because when I save driver as a fulltime driver. because fulltime driver no need to fill start_time field.

Comment: When you say start_time field do you mean in the form request or in the database? if you mean database you can set the column to allow NULL entry's and if you mean the request then use an or operator? and check this on the controller like isset($Variable) ? $Variable : '...blank value...';

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127510/discussion-between-andrew-vanusi-and-birdy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After our chat here is my propsal, It may work just from a slight change on your pta['start_time'] array value.

```
public function saveHandler(Request $request, $obj)
{
    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();
            $obj->fill($request->all());
            if (!$obj->save()) {
                throw new ValidationException($obj->errors());
            }
            foreach($request->parttimeAvailabilities as $pta) {
                \Log::info($pta);
                if (empty($pta['id'])) { 
                    $parttimeAvailability = new PartTimeAvailability();
                }
                else {
                    $parttimeAvailability = PartTimeAvailability::find($pta['id']);
                }
                $parttimeAvailability->driver()->associate($obj);
                $pta['driver_id'] = isset($pta['driver_id']);
                $parttimeAvailability->day = $pta['day'];
                $parttimeAvailability->start_time = isset($pta['start_time']) ? $pta['start_time'] : '00:00:00';
                $parttimeAvailability->end_time = $pta['end_time'];
                $parttimeAvailability->available = isset($pta['available']);
                $parttimeAvailability->save();
            };
            $obj->save();
            if (!$parttimeAvailability->save()) {
                throw new ValidationException($parttimeAvailability->errors());
            }
        DB::commit();
        return $this->sendSuccessResponse($request);
    } catch (ValidationException $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        \Log::error($e->errors);
        return $this->sendErrorResponse($request, $e->errors);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        \Log::error($e->getMessage());
        return $this->sendErrorResponse($request,'Unable to process. Please contact system Administrator');
    }

}
```

You said you believe the issue is from your $pta['start_time'] being empty / null on the post request well you can use the operator to check if isset and if the value isset then use it and if not use a blank value as your database allows for nullable entries on that specific value.

Give it a shot and let me know, Hopefully it fixes the issue if not ill see about helping the best i can, Im no expert though :)

I have updated this answer due to your validation rules?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Laravel threw a `Undefined index:'some_field'` exception, 
because  I accessed the field `value(some_field)` to evaluate it, but that field is not sent by the client app.

So in this case, we have to use `function isset($response['some_field'])` before accessing it. I hope this answer may help someone.